# Question about the efficiency of closure/encapsulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, performance, closures

I'm somewhat new to JavaScript, so bear with me if this is a dumb question.

Let's say that I've got a "class" that looks like this:

```
var obj = function () {
    var val;
    return {
        setVal: function(newVal) {
            val = newVal;
        },
        getVal: function() {
            return val;
        }
    };
};
```

Assuming my syntax is correct, this defines a class with a "private" property named "value," with methods to set/get the property.  Now, I will create two objects from this class:

```
var myObj = obj();
var yourObj = obj();
```

Does this create a separate setVal() and getVal() method for *each* object? If not, why not? If so, is this a serious concern when building efficient web applications? Is the trade-off (if any) of  efficiency for closure worth it in most/all contexts? Am I dumb?

Thanks,
Gerard

Comment: here is a good article on closures and prototyping. http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2008/12/javascript-inheritance-via-prototypes-and-closures

Comment: This is an excellent question to ask if your just starting out in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = function () {
    var val;
    return {
        setVal: function(newVal) {
            val = newVal;
        },
        getVal: function() {
            return val;
        }
    };
};
```

what this function does is as following :

- create variable named `val`
- create new object
- create a new function and assign it to field `setVal`
- create a new function and assign it to field `getVal`
- return object.

So your always creating 4 new things.

This isn't really a problem if you have less then a 1000 objects on the page. Refactoring it away is a micro optimisation.

The alternative would be to not rely on local variables and use `this._val` to indicate that `val` is private.

Answer (score 0):

It does do so conceptually. However, since this is such a common pattern, modern JavaScript JITers know how to optimize it away so that there is only one copy of the code stored in memory, with appropriate pointer redirections to make it work with the relevant closure.

EDIT: although I am not really up for spelunking through source code, here's some basic proof. [Download the Chrome dev channel release](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel), and take heap snapshots before and after running the following code:

```
var obj = /* as above */;

var objs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    objs.push(obj());
}
```

Then do the same for this code:

```
function Obj() { }
Obj.prototype.setVal = function (value) { this._val = value; };
Obj.prototype.getVal = function () { return this._val; };

var objs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    objs.push(new Obj());
}
```

You will find the heap snapshots to show the same numbers for "Code" in both cases, so indeed the optimization I describe is being performed.

Comment: It still creates two instances of methods `setVal` and `getVal`

Comment: Yes, in JavaScript that is true. But there is no loss of efficiency because on the machine-code level that modern JITers compile to, there is only one instance of each.

Comment: please back that up with links to the V8 and Jaegermonkey source. I would imagine there are multiple instances of all those functions each with pointers to the correct Closure context. If there are actually only two functions then that's really impressive as an optimisation

Comment: -1 Not only is this kind of optimization impossible (each closure is a separate state, and requires to be held in memory somewhere) but you can clearly see the javascript memory usage sky rocketing in the closure method vs the prototype method. +3MB per call vs +almost nothing per call for the prototype.